# python virtualenv can not access file in home directory

Tags: python, linux, django, virtualenv

I am using this code in `Django` settings to construct the DB path

```
from os.path import expanduser
defautl_db_path = expanduser("~")+"/db.sqlite3"
```

The code runs well if I installed Django system wide but if I run the application inside `virtualenv` the application throws an exception saying `unable to open database file`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you confirm the result of `os.path.expanduser("~")` is appropriate? You may need to configure the env variable `WORKON_HOME` for virtualenv wrapper.

Comment: I opened a python shell session from within the virtualenv and the output of `os.path.expanduser('~')` is correct.

Comment: You could maybe show how the path was used in your DB settings

Comment: Hmm. Can you provide a full traceback of the error? Also I'm assuming you activated the virtualenv.

Answer (score 1):

did you check permissions on the home directory of the process owner?
Is it true, that you are using a Unix OS?

Most likely the django user is www-data.

If you checked this, you could try to address home directory of a specific user by adding username to ~.

```
from os.path import expanduser
defautl_db_path = expanduser("~www-data")+"/db.sqlite3"
```

In documentation is written:

os.path.expanduser(path)
On Unix and Windows, return the argument with an initial component of ~ or ~user replaced by that user‘s home directory.

On Unix, an initial ~ is replaced by the environment variable HOME if it is set; otherwise the current user’s home directory is looked up in the password directory through the built-in module pwd. An initial ~user is looked up directly in the password directory.

Comment: This answer may be a bit premature. Answers should not require clarification from the asker. If you need to ask clarification, a comment should be used. Once you have enough reputation on stack overflow, you'll be allowed to add comments to questions. Cheers!

Comment: I am running the application using the built-in server './manage.py runserver' so the user of the process is my user not apache user.

Comment: Trydefautl_db_path = expanduser("~<your user>")+"/db.sqlite3"